# Horizontally and vertically center a figure and scale to fill the whole page in landspape orientation

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, scaling, landscape

I want to have an image that fills a landscape page.

I have tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %Gives us landscape pages with begin{landscape}. Use this for pages with very large diagrams.
\usepackage{geometry} %change margin on individual page \newgeometry{} and \restoreometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %nicer captions
\usepackage{float}%exact placement of floats (things inside a begin{})

\usepackage{todonotes}  %For the minium working example

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{landscape}

  \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
  \thispagestyle{empty} %disable page numbering for this page

    \vfill
      \begin{center}
        \begin{figure}
          \missingfigure[figwidth = \paperwidth]{picture}
          \label{label32}
          \caption{a big image}
        \end{figure}
      \end{center}
    \vfill

  \restoregeometry
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

But this places the image in the top right corner of the landscape page, and its not even scaled that big. If I use `\centering` inside the figure environment instead of creating a center environment, the figure is then put in the bottom corner.

How can I place it so that it is horizontally and vertically centered, and it fills the page, with about a 1 or 2 cm margin?

These requirements are all flexible if you have a better suggestion. My main goal is to display an image with lots of fine detail, only visible when it scaled up to just less than A4 size.

I am using the pdflatex compiler, and hence I am using the `pdflscape` package. My document type is a report, and cannot be changed.

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Don’t use the `figure` environment, to begin with: it is meant for creating floating insertions, which is not what you want.  Before answering, I would like to see a Minimal Working Example, complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I've edited the question so that it includes a minimal working example. I've also included packages that may effect the solution.

Comment: Also, do I not have to use the figure environment so that it numbers correctly, and so I can add a caption to it? It also needs to appear in the list of figures.

Comment: Sorry, I did’t see your edit before posting my answer: I’ll try to see if I have still got time to examine your code.  EDIT: I understand now that you _do_ want a `figure`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure of what you want to achieve and what limitations you have got, but, to begin with, you might want to have a look at the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mwe} % for sample figures -- automatically loads graphicx

\begin{document}

Preceding stuff.

\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[c][0pt][c]{\columnwidth}
        \centerline{%
            \includegraphics
                [width=\dimexpr\paperheight-2cm\relax]
                {image}%
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

Subsequent stuff.

\end{document}
```

Notice that `\paperheight` remains `\paperheight` even in landscape orientation.  I (or other people, since I must disconnect, now) will make further adjustments if thi is not exactly what you want.

**Addition**

It turned out that the OP wants to caption the figure: this can be done within the `minipage` environment itself by means of `\captionof` command from the *caption* package.  Recourse to a floating `figure` environment is best avoided, in my opinion, since the geometry and page style settings wouldn’t be very robust (what if other preceding floats were waiting to be placed on a page themselves?).

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\bigbreak

Preceding stuff.

\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[c][0pt][c]{\columnwidth}
        \centerline{%
            \includegraphics[
                        width=\dimexpr\paperheight-2cm\relax,
                        height=10cm % assuming your image is short enough that 
                                    % it does not overprint the caption
                    ]{image}%
        }
        \centering
        \captionof{figure}{A nice figure}
        \label{fig:label}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

Subsequent stuff, with a reference to figure~\ref{fig:label}.

\end{document}
```

I am assuming that the image is not so tall that the caption is pushed off the page, of course.

Comment: This almost works, but I cannot caption it, and it does not appear in the list of figures. (See edited code in main question). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Found the answer. I'll post it as a new answer here now.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I agree, using a floating figure environment could cause problems. Also, yes, my image is not tall, hence why I wanted it on a landscape page :).

Comment: @Blue7: Yet it is true that `\newgeometry` begins with `\clearpage`!  But try, for instance, having some text in the `landscape` environment, alongside with the `figure`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Gustavo Mezzetti's answer, the image can be placed in a figure environment so it can be captioned and listed in the `\listoffigures`. A few other modifications are required, shown below.

The `\paperheight` adjustment (`-6cm`) needs to be manually tuned depending on the aspect ratio of your image. This is best done by eye anyway, as an automatic process wouldn't know what looks best.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %Gives us landscape pages with begin{landscape}. Use this for pages with very large diagrams.
\usepackage{geometry} %change margin on individual page \newgeometry{} and \restoreometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %nicer captions
\usepackage{float}%exact placement of floats (things inside a begin{})
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{empty} %disable page numbering for this page
        \begin{figure}
           \centering
           \includegraphics [width=\dimexpr\paperheight-6cm\relax]{image}
          \label{label32}
          \caption{a big image}
        \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Here it is as a command. Put this in the document preamble:

```
%Command to insert a landscape page filled with a centred figure.
%The arguments are: {marginsize}{tunable parameter to adjust for aspect ratio}{caption}{imagepath}
%Example usage: \hFigure{1cm}{2cm}{This is a big image}{pics/myImage.png}
\newcommand{\hFigure}[4]{
\newgeometry{left=#1,right=#1,top=#1,bottom=#1}
\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{empty} %disable page numbering for this page
\vfill
        \begin{figure}
           \centering
           \includegraphics [width=\dimexpr\paperheight-#2\relax]{#4}
          \label{label32}
          \caption{#3}
        \end{figure}
\vfill
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
}
```

Comment: Very good, I’m going to upvote! :-)  Are you interested in seeing the code I worked out in the meanwhile?  Then, I must really go.